# Recommend data structure for snapshoted data

Tags: python, r, algorithm, data-modeling

I have delimited log files which capture a snapshot of some processes every 5 minutes. I'd like to do some statistical analysis on them, grouping and charting sub-sets of the data, etc. part of which would involve counting the time the process was open (i.e. total minutes = how snapshots it appears in x 5). I can use Python, R, or whatever language I choose.

**The challenge is that *none* of the fields are unique (there are one-to-many and many-to-many relationships), so the only match is when *every* element on the entire line is the same.**

Maybe an example will help. Let's say the first snapshot log looks like this:

```
R123,M,5,... <-- line A
R190,Z,4,...
R663,M,8,...
```

Then 5 minutes later, the next snapshot shows this:

```
R123,M,5,... <-- line A
R123,P,3,... <-- line B
R955,Z,3,...
```

Clearly the process in line A has now been around for at least 5 minutes now. But even though line B has the same first field, the other fields don't match so it's not the same process.

I'm just trying to figure out a good data model that makes this data easy to work with.

One option would be a simple frequency count: read every entire line into a Python dict or Perl hash with the line as the key, such that when a duplicate line appears in the next snapshot it just adds to the count. For example in Perl: `$count{$_}++ foreach @lines;`

But would a full line of data even be valid as a dictionary key? And what about non-contiguous instances, like if line A appears for 3 snapshots in a row then another day later appears again?--those ought to be separate instances so that time-based queries are still valid.

**Any suggestions for me on how I might process & store this data?**

Comment: Why not pull out the duplicated lines? There is a `duplicated` function that has a dataframe method.

Comment: @DWin: 'cause I need to quantify he duplicated lines, since the key data about how long that process lasted is only found by seeing how many times or how long from its first appearance to its last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question -- sure, at least in Perl you can use any string as a hash key. No limits.

Next: evaluate the snapshots sequentially. At snapshot 1, just read everything into memory and assign a counter 0 to each item. Proceed to snapshot 2. At snapshot N, proceed as follows: Anything new is stored in the memory and assigned a count of 0. Anything that was already in memory is kept in the memory with an increased counter. Anything that is in the memory, but is no longer in the current snapshot gets filed to the output file.

If you are worried about the size of the log files, instead of Perl's hash use an SQL database, for example SQLite via DBI.

Comment: Hmm... reading sequentially could allow me to make my own unique ID for each process, solve the problem with non-contiguous instances, and make it fit into a relational-DB well. Definitely a good possibility.